# Android:How to pass intent listview to webview?

Tags: android

I have one list of some HTML page.
When I click on list particular url link is open in WebView.
But here when i click on list webview page is open but it is blank.below is code  for how pass intent to webview.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " +DataArray.title[position],  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       String Keyword =DataArray.DocUrl[position];
       Intent intent = new Intent(DocList.this, ViewDoc.class);
       intent.putExtra("docFileName", Keyword);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

another class for webview. its code is below

```
public class ViewDoc extends Activity {

private String filename;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Intent i = getIntent();
         Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
         filename = extras.getString("docFileName");

         WebView wb = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
         wb.loadUrl(filename);


    }

}
```

This code is working perfectly for videoview.

So please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forget setContentView.

```
setContentView(wb);
```

Comment: Thanks.I put setContentView(wb);

Comment: but now it is show page is not available.In simple webview example it is show.

Comment: Your filename should be like this: "file:///sdcard/index.html" instead of "/sdcard/index.html"